# Make form use ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am having issue making a form be sent using ajax.

Here is my code:

```
<form id="form" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>


$('#submit').click(function(event){
    alert('ajax');
});
```

The "ajax" alert shows, but then the page gets reloaded! How can I stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$('#submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('ajax');        
});
```

Comment: With `preventDefault`, is there any reason to still use the (much earlier style) `return false`?

Comment: And if you're going to be doing this a lot, think about using the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).  It'll make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

use [$.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) instead of click :)

```
$('#form').submit(function(event){
    alert('ajax');
    // here some ajax functions for sending via get or post ;)
    return false; // this stops loading the action site.. its something like e.preventDefault() on links
});
```